# No CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER could be found

Tags: c++, cmake, compiler-errors, fortran

I am using CMake for my c++ and Fortran projects. I use the Intel Fortran compiler and VS2017. Every time I try to configure the project in the CMake-gui I get this error:

```
The Fortran compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at Lib/Fast_Table/CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
  No CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER could be found.
```

I have looked all over the internet for the solution and I can't seem to find any solution for my problem. The Paths all seem correct and match other peers with the same project.

Here are the errors that show up in the CMakeError.log file:

```
Compiling the Fortran compiler identification source file "CMakeFortranCompilerId.F" failed.
Package 'IFLangServicePackage' failed to load.
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'ifconsol.lib'
```

The .F file in the error above compiles on it's own and so do other VS2017 Fortran projects I have tried to build in VS2017. It's the configuration and generation process in the cmake-gui that is giving these errors.

Comment: My installations of VS2017 and Intel Fortran were not setting up correctly. I had to go to the Intel Fortran solution in my build directory under .\CMakeFiles\3.18.4\CompilerIdFortran. I opened the project in Visual Studio. Tools >> Options >> Intel Compilers and Tools >> Visual Fortran >> Compilers. Then I went to the x64 tab and instead of having "Latest" selected, I selected "Intel(R) Visual Fortran Compiler 19.1.0.166 [Intel(R) 64]" and this had the proper setup for compiling Fortran. There were also some files in the 2020 compilers_and_libraries dir that were not in the 2020.0.166 dir.

Comment: I think it is worth posting your solution as an answer to aid others in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

My installations of VS2017 and Intel Fortran were not setting up correctly. I had to go to the Intel Fortran solution in my build directory under .\CMakeFiles\3.18.4\CompilerIdFortran. I opened the project in Visual Studio. Tools >> Options >> Intel Compilers and Tools >> Visual Fortran >> Compilers. Then I went to the x64 tab and instead of having "Latest" selected, I selected "Intel(R) Visual Fortran Compiler 19.1.0.166 [Intel(R) 64]" and this had the proper setup for compiling Fortran. There were also some files in the 2020 compilers_and_libraries dir that were not in the 2020.0.166 dir.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).